# Give an example of a quadratic polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$ which is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$, but is not irreducible in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Give an example of a quadratic polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$ which is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$, but is not irreducible in $\Bbb R[x]$.

I was thinking perhaps, if we let $p(x) = x^2 - 2$ then we have that since $p(x) = x^2 - 2 = (x + \sqrt 2)(x - \sqrt 2)$. $2$ is rational but the roots are irrational. Irrational numbers are a subgroup of the reals. So this should satisfy the condition but I'm not sure if this is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your counter-example is fine, $p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ as it has degree $2$ and has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$. However, $p$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ as it is the product of two non-invertible elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

More generally, if $p$ is prime, it follows from [Eisenstein criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) that $X^2-p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, any polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$ with a positive discriminant which is not a square in $\mathbf Q$ will be an example.

In particular, by the *Rational roots theorem*, any monic polynomial with integer coefficients, such that no divisor of the constant term is a root, will be an example.